# How do I position a TextBox in Word that I've just added to a page

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I have a document that has a number of rectangle shapes.  I want to replace each of those with a TextBox in exactly the same place.
My starting point is working with an existing known shape I want to replace with a textbox (later I'll add further automation to process the selected shape or all shapes).

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
Dim shp As Shape
Dim Box As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 1928"))
    shp.Select
    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=shp.Left, Top:=shp.Top, Width:=shp.Width, Height:=shp.Height)
    Box.RelativeHorizontalPosition = shp.RelativeHorizontalPosition
    Box.RelativeVerticalPosition = shp.RelativeVerticalPosition
    Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Some text"
Next shp

End Sub
```

I've tried setting a number of other properties but the textbox always appears and stays at the top centre of the document page.

Thank you for any guidance you can offer.

Regards
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, rt As Long, rl As Long, wf As Long, Shp As Shape
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Shapes(1)
      If .Type = msoAutoShape Then
        wf = .WrapFormat.Type
        rt = .TopRelative
        rl = .LeftRelative
        Set Shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
          Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height, Anchor:=.Anchor)
        With Shp
          .WrapFormat.Type = wf
          .TopRelative = rt
          .LeftRelative = rl
          .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello World"
        End With
        .Delete
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In my opinion you don't need to crate a TextBox, you can simply change the existing box as follow:

```
Dim shp As Shape
Dim Box As Shape

scount = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count

For i = 1 To scount
    Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Some txt"
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Next i
```